# How do you search for characters in csv.reader() object?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I'm trying to look for a character/word in an csv.reader() object.

I was sure this would work:

```
freader = csv.reader(f)
z = freader.next()
print z

if "EE" in z:
    print "Found"
else:
    print "NOPE"
```

but it doesn't.. 
Here's the output:

```
['1 EE-43-JT-32439 Time;"1 EE-43-JT-32439 ValueY"']
NOPE
```

Anyone got any good suggestions on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: You need to check the items in the list.

Comment: like: if "EE" in z[0] f.eks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check inside the list.

```
for item in z:
   if "EE" in item:
       print "Found"
       break   # You can break the loop if the item is exits.
   else:
       print "NOPE"
```

You can understand the real difference here.

```
In [196]: 'EE' in ['1 EE-43-JT-32439 Time;"1 EE-43-JT-32439 ValueY"']
Out[196]: False
In [197]: 'EE' in ['1 EE-43-JT-32439 Time;"1 EE-43-JT-32439 ValueY"'][0]
Out[197]: True
```

Comment: @user2927356 Cool :)